Review proof that One-Time Pad is a perfectly secure private-key encryption scheme
Review the following proof of the property of "Perfect Secrecy (Perfect Security)" of the "One-Time Pad (OTP)" symmetric encryption scheme. In other words, the proof that OTP is a perfectly secure private-key encryption scheme.

We begin by defining Symmetric Encryption:
A tuple $(KeyGen,E,D)$ is a symmetric encryption scheme over the sets $K$ (key space), $M$ (message space), and $C$ (ciphertext space) if all algorithms are efficient and satisfy the following:

$KeyGen(1^{n}) \rightarrow k$: the key generation is a randomised algorithm that returns a key $k$.
$E(k,m) \rightarrow c$: the encryption is a possibly randomised algorithm that on input a key $k$ and a (plaintext) message $m$, outputs a ciphertext $c$.
$D(k,c) \rightarrow m$: the decryption is a deterministic algorithm that on input a key $k$ and ciphertext $c$, ouputs a plaintext message $m$.

We also require that $P[D(k,E(k,m))=m | k \leftarrow KeyGen(1^{n})] = 1$ for correctness. Meaning, decrypting an encrypted message should yield the original message given that the same key is used.
Note: The notation $1^{n}$ in $KeyGen(1^{n})$ is commonly seen in cryptography literature and refers to a unary representation of the integer $n$. Meaning, it's a bitstring of $n$ ones. E.g. $1^{3}$ would be "111".

Now we define Perfect Secrecy (Perfect Security):
A symmetric encryption scheme $(KeyGen,E,D)$ is perfectly secret if for all pair of messages $m_{0},m_{1} \in M$ and for all ciphertexts $c \in C$ it holds that $$P(c \leftarrow E(k,m_{0})|k \leftarrow KeyGen(1^{n})] = P(c \leftarrow E(k,m_{1}) | k \leftarrow KeyGen(1^{n})]$$
The idea here, according to my understanding, is that it is saying that for every pair of messages, the probabilities that either message maps to a given ciphertext $c$ must be equal. Which makes sense if we want to avoid leaking in your ciphertext. It should be impossible for an adversary to gain information regarding what message could have produced the observed ciphertext.

Now let's try and prove that the OTP symmetric encryption scheme is perfectly secure.
We begin by defining a few things:

$K=M=C=\{0,1\}^{n}$ where $\{0,1\}^{n}$ refers to the set of all binary strings of length $n$. E.g. $\{0,1\}^{2} = \{00,01,10,11\}$.

$KeyGen(1^{n}) : k \leftarrow \\\$\{0,1\}^{n}$ where the dollar sign (\$) refers to drawing from the set uniformly,

$E(k,m) = k \oplus m$,

$D(k,c) = k \oplus c$.


We also assume that correctness holds for all $k$, and all $m:D(k,E(k,m) = k \oplus c = k \oplus (k \oplus m) = m$.
We also know that for every message $m$ and ciphertext $c$ there exists exactly one key $k \in \{0,1\}^{n}$ such that $c=E(k,m)$. The key is simply $k = m \oplus c$. This uniqueness property stems from the bijective property of the XOR operation. Given the pair $(k,m)$, the ciphertext $c$ is unique. Conversely, for any fixed $m$ and $c$, there is exactly one key $k$ that satisfies $c = k \oplus m$.
This is also supported by Shannon's Theorem (1940s) that says if a symmetric encryption scheme $(KeyGen,E,D)$ defined over $(K,M,C)$ has perfect security then $|K| \geq |M|$. If we have less keys than we have messages, then at least two messages must have been created from the same key according to the pigeonhole principle, thus we would lose correctness.
Thus, we can say that
$$ P[E(k,m) \rightarrow c | k \leftarrow KeyGen(1^{n})] = P[c \oplus m \leftarrow KeyGen(1^{n})] = \frac{1}{|K|} $$
The probability of the key $k$ producing the ciphertext $c$ when encrypting $m$ is equal to the probability of drawing that key. The probability of drawing that key is simply $\frac{1}{|K|}$ assuming that we are drawing uniformly from the set of all keys.
Recall that if we want a perfectly secure private-key encryption scheme, then it must hold that for all pair of messages, the probabilities that either message maps to a given ciphertext $c$ must be equal.
So, given that we showed that $P[E(k,m) \rightarrow c | k \leftarrow KeyGen(1^{n})] = \frac{1}{|K|}$ for all $m \in M$, then it must be true that
$$ P[E(k,m_{0}) \rightarrow c | k \leftarrow KeyGen(1^{n})] = \frac{1}{|K|} = P[E(k,m_{1}) \rightarrow c | k \leftarrow KeyGen(1^{n})] $$.
Q.E.D.


What is the question? Just "review this proof"?

@Mikero I had a question, but I happened to stumble upon the answer while writing this post. A classic case of "rubber duck programming". As such, the result was just me spitting out a proof. So, sure, it's just a "review this proof" at this point.
